# Quick way to take a rectangle screenshot, draw a circle, and then copy clipboard

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, xubuntu

I have xfce4-screenshooter that allows me to select part of the screen to print screen, however I would like the selection to automatically open up a very simple image editor that lets me draw circles or triangles before putting the screenshot+drawing into the clipboard.

System: Ubuntu 22.04, xfce4 (Xubuntu).

Tried:

- `pinta`: unavailable dependency
- `gimp`: large and clunky (slow startup)
- `mtpaint`: how to draw an ellipsis?
- `kolourpaint`: unavailable dependency
- `shutter`: How to draw an ellipsis with few clicks. How to export image to clipboard?

I tried to install pinta but that wasnt a failure due to dependencies + behind a proxy. What are other simple image editors to consider? (simple as in lightweight/small/few dependencies/fast to start)

```
$ sudo apt install pinta
...
E: Failed to fetch http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-icon-theme/gnome-icon-theme_3.12.0-4_all.deb
```

Comment: I use IrfanView under Wine. Nothing comes close to this simple image viewing/converting/drawing (invoked via `F12`) application in Linux.

Comment: Why not solve some of the dependencies?

Comment: @FelixJN sure, how?

Comment: @Moberg quite impossible to answer without details, but a generic approach is shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: @FelixJN Thanks, I'm not sure if I will be able to follow any steps of that because I'm not allowed to modify the apt repository sources (ppt?).

Comment: I don't know if either of `pinta` and `kolourpaint` would solve your problem, but they're both available through their respective websites as both Flatpak and Snap packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend trying `Flameshot` (https://flameshot.org/). It allows taking a screenshot of part of the screen, provides editing tools that allow drawing on the screenshot, and allows putting the result in the clipboard. There are tools for drawing circles, ellipses, and rectangles; unfortunately none for triangles, but they can be constructed using the line tool or drawn freehand using the pencil tool.

Comment: That looks really nice, thank you! There are some quirks and things to learn (there seemed to be problem with Wayland(?) and the "bubble tool icons" appear at almost random locations) but the spirit is exactly what I was after, thanks again :)

Comment: The button positions do _seem_ to be almost random. But, unless I'm mistaken, there's a pattern to it: They start at the bottom-left of the screenshot and are positioned in counter-clockwise order around it from there.

Comment: Also, if there are buttons you'd never use, you can uncheck them on the Interface tab of the Configuration dialog to hide them.